# How to find the last bit of corruption/crimson/hallow in a terraria world

Tags: terraria

I have been working on getting my main Terraria world to 100% pure(No Hallow Crimson Or Corruption) and I managed to get the world to 1% Hallow and 1% Crimson but can not find those last 1%s. I have tried using Tedit to find the coordinates of the last blocks but that did not work and I have also tried the MoreTerraria world viewer to find those last blocks but it keeps giving me an error when I try to draw a world. If anyone has any tips or tricks for finding this last bit I would gladly try them because every solution I have found online does not help me in the slightest. I am also trying to stay away from destroying the world since it is my main world and would prefer not to look over the entire world as it is a large world which means that by the time I found it, it probably would have spread more already.

If needed here is the [world download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ecntecksuj4k2ag/Plumbers_FTW.wld?dl=0) if there are no efficient tips and tricks that can work so that I may at least get some help finding the round about area the crimson and hallow is.

Comment: If you wait a few days, any existing crimson and hallow will spread, making them easier to find in an editor.

Comment: If you're at that stage in the game, you should be able to afford the Clentaminator and the coloured solutions that it uses to rid the world of corruption easily even if you don't know the location.

Comment: @GeorgeWillcox I have been using that to get rid of the corruption and you may think it's easy but it has a limited range meaning I am unable to just run across the top of may world and spray it down it just doesn't work like that meaning just one pesky little block can make it really hard to actually use.

Comment: @BrandonRankin I have a lot of experience in Terraria and know of the clentaminator's limited range. Digging horizontal tunnels or hellevators may help, but it would probably be easier (and cheaper) to wait for the corruption to spread

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have mentioned TEdit, I am assuming you are fine with using the tool.

The last tool on the toolbar, called the "Morph Tool" will allow you to change the biome of any region in its brush. Under the "Morph to Biome" option, select "Purify." You can now use the morph tool to remove corruption/crimson/hallow in the brush area.

Turn the brush size up to max and move it across your world to purify it.

---

An alternative is to create hellavator shafts across the map spread apart at approximate 25 tiles and spray the Clentaminator across both sides.

Comment: You haven't added any images...

Answer (score 1):

One guaranteed way of clearing out a tainted area is to dig a "hellevator" (a 2-wide tunnel straight down to the underworld) every screen width apart. Then, use a clentaminator to purify the world. Unfortunately, this method is very expensive and leaves your world scarred. It's tedious to clean up if you want to make the world look nice again. If you're dead-set against creating multiple hellevators in your world, the only realistic way to locate the missing Corruption/Crimson/Hallow is to examine the world in a third-party viewing tool.

There are several of them available:

- [TEdit](https://www.binaryconstruct.com/tedit/) is a Terraria world editor which will allow you to not only view the world, but also make changes (including simply removing the tainted area right away).
- [TerraMap](https://terramap.github.io) is a world viewer that allows you to highlight blocks for easy location finding. This will probably be helpful to you for finding the tainted area. Once located, you can just go over there in-game and clear it out.
- [MoreTerra](https://github.com/mike-mo/MoreTerra) is another world viewer which creates an image file of your world with icons for certain special items (chests, heart containers, gems, etc.). This one doesn't come with any special location tracking, so it might be the hardest to make use of, since you'll have to manually search for the affected blocks... however it is still an option.